# How to remove certain unwanted files from a Torrent file?

Tags: python, scripting, torrent

I have a list of torrent files (2000) in a folder. Each torrent file contains about 500 downloadable files. Around 1 million total downloadable files. I only want to download some of them that match a certain criteria.

I have created a dictionary in Python that contains torrent file names as keys and a list of files I want to download from that torrent as the values.

```
{'1200.torrent', ['abc.pdf', 'xyz.txt'...]}
```

Is there a way to decode the Torrent file and remove the unwanted files from it (or select the ones I do need) and output that to another Torrent file which can be set to download automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this lib to parse *.torrent files](https://github.com/eliasson/pieces/blob/master/pieces/bencoding.py) and make result dict.

Decode example:

```
from pieces.bencoding import Decoder
Decoder(b'i123e').decode()
```

Working with torrent file:

```
with open('file-name.torrent', 'rb') as f:
    meta_info = f.read()
    torrent = Decoder(meta_info).decode()
```

in `torrent` you'll find all decoded information including file names and meta data. Make your own parser and store result dictionary for next processing.

Comment: The parsing of the torrent file works fine, but when I re-create the torrent file after having modified the files dictionary it doesn't work because the hash values change due to the modification.

Comment: You need to create torrent file in reverse way: encode data with Decoder (method encode()) and then write to a file in the binary mode.